# fiddler debugging question pertaining to vba use of winhttp

Tags: vba, fiddler, winhttp

I have what i think is a simple question, but cannot find it on fiddlers website or with goggle. I'm trying to download a file with vba, using winhttp. To me my request looks good, but fails.I successfully used fiddlers "composer" to simulate the request & it worked. I cannot see any real difference between my vba/winhttp request & the composer. My question is fiddler doesn't capture my vba requests when i send them. I want to view the inspector details & compare more precisely. Can I set fiddler to capture my vba traffic & if so how?  Thank you! -Jim

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/using-fiddler-with-winhttp

Comment: Tim, that was exactly it. I just did it for the first time, ran it, it captured my vba job & I believe I've found my error straight away. Thank you so much, that was the answer.-Jim